# Tornado with Facebook Registration Plugin

Tags: facebook, tornado

Facebook released released a registration plugin here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/user_registration few weeks ago.

I was wondering how can we implement this with Tornado?

I kept receiving an error: 403 POST /auth/fbform (127.0.0.1): '_xsrf' argument missing from POST

The redirect_url is http://localhost:8888/auth/fbform
And the code is as follows:

```
class FBFormLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        print "i'm in GET"
        print self.request
        # parse and check data
        data = _parse_signed_request(self.request['_xsrf'], "XXXXX")
        return
    def post(self):
        print "i'm in POST"
        print self.request
        # parse and check data
        data = _parse_signed_request(self.request['_xsrf'], "XXXXX")
        return

    def _parse_signed_request(signed_request, app_secret):
        print "hello in parse_signed_request"
        try:
          l = signed_request.split('.', 2)
          encoded_sig = str(l[0])
          payload = str(l[1])
        except IndexError:
          raise ValueError("'signed_request' malformed")

        sig = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encoded_sig + "=" * ((4 - len(encoded_sig) % 4) % 4))
        data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(payload + "=" * ((4 - len(payload) % 4) % 4))

        data = json.loads(data)

        if data.get('algorithm').upper() != 'HMAC-SHA256':
          raise ValueError("'signed_request' is using an unknown algorithm")
        else:
          expected_sig = hmac.new(app_secret, msg=payload, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()

        if sig != expected_sig:
          raise ValueError("'signed_request' signature mismatch")
        else:
          return data
```

I do not understand which POST the error message is talking about, so
I tried to use the _parse_signed_request from the get and post function.

Please enlighten me.
I'm currently working from my local computer by the way.

Best Regards.

Comment: Tornado has [inbuilt support for Facebook authentication](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/auth.html?highlight=facebook#facebook). You can skip most headaches with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disabled CSRF checking on that endpoint since the request is coming from Facebook and not your own site

http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation#cross-site-request-forgery-protection